# Google stock graphs: What does the percentage point refer to?

Tags: stocks, google-finance

I'm new to investing.

I noticed with [Google stock graphs](https://www.google.com/search?ei=s8mTXo-CH4WLytMP9aeFqA4&q=tesla%20stock&oq=tesla%20stock&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQDFAAWABg0CdoAHAAeACAAQCIAQCSAQCYAQCqAQdnd3Mtd2l6&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjPp92DqeToAhWFhXIEHfVTAeUQ4dUDCAw) I can get information about a slice of the graph by clicking on two different points along the line:

[image]

Question:

What does the percentage point refer to? From where has the stock risen 58.63%?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tesla has risen $211.78 during the time period demarcated by the two vertical lines.

The current price is $573.00 on 4/09/20

The earlier price is $361.22 on 3/18/20

$211.78 divided by $361.22 is 58.63% which is the gain for this time period and it is indicated on your chart.